# How to renumber usb audio playback devices windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, playback

I always forget how i fix this, but in the audio playback devices in windows 10, windows will start sequentially numbering a device anytime you replug the device into a new USB port, there is a way to reset these with registry edits, but I recall there being a simple software utility to more easily do it, anyone know how to do it either way? thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Bobby S' answer seems to be working, but it *might not always* be enough to reset the counter (at least on Win10 21H1).

You should be sure to also enable hidden devices by setting `[View] > "Show hidden devices"`.
After that you *also* can uninstall all disabled / hidden instances of your device.
Keep in mind: for audio devices there are two listings to uninstall from `"Audio inputs and outputs"` & `"Sound, video and game controllers"`
([Example of both listings having the affected device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbrs2.png))

After a restart you should have a clean installed device. Remember, the device might need to be setup again (volume, effects, gain, etc.).

[Clean install of my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib0fS.png)

---

Source: [This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/ewnysz/how_to_rename_audio_devices_like_2_realtek_series/) and my own attempts.

Answer (score 2):

ok figured it out again, it's as simple as uninstalling the desired usb audio device in windows device manager, reboot, and voila, your playback devices numbers will be reset/removed. hope that helps someone